# Issue with jquery onclick (not triggering)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am having a strange issue.

I have created a code snippet where the user can create dynamic input elements and remove them as well

When I click the remove class then it's not triggering the onclick event.

```
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<div id="TextBoxesGroup"></div>
```

I have created a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/b4Cs8/2/

Comment: `$('body').on("click","a.removeField", function () {$(this).parent().remove();});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event delegation` in jquery

```
$(document).on("click" , "a.removeField", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().remove();
     counter--;            
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Cs8/3/)

Comment: @downvoter care to comment. What mistake i done in the above code?

Comment: Thanks Sudharsan. It worked. Also updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/b4Cs8/4/ Thanks once again.

Comment: @Raj - you missed counter value decrement. please check my answer

Comment: Do we need a counter to decrease the value at all?